# What is the correct way to escape UNC paths?

Tags: vimscript, external-command, microsoft-windows, filesystem

Let's say there is a file `\\server-42\tmp\dir\test.txt`.  When my plugin tries to execute this command via `system()` it triggers an error:

```
cd "\\server-42\tmp\dir" && git ls-files --error-unmatch --full-name test.txt
```

The error is `E484: Can't open file C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Temp\blah.tmp`.

The directory is produced by `shellescape(fnamemodify(filepath, ':h')`, where `filepath` is the full path to file.  The file is produced by `shellescape(fnamemodify(filepath, ':t')`.

How can I get this to work?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: that will be hardly possible, since I believe Windows cmd does not support UNC paths at all (Try `cd \\server-42\temp\dir`) You would have to map the network drive to drive letter and work with that I believe

Comment: Windows supports `\\hostname\path` (for almost as long as I can remember...I'm dating myself)...they call it a 'network path', though. :P  I haven't tried to use them in Vim, though.

Comment: Windows does, but not the command line subsystem of Windows. However, it seems like you might be able to use `pushd` and `popd` [instead](https://superuser.com/a/399885/85228)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt My bad. My eyes skipped right over 'cmd'.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Good to know that cmd does not support UNC paths at all.  Also, `pushd` seems to work – thanks!  I'll be happy to accept if you add it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is, that the commandline subsystem on Windows does not support UNC paths. (Try running cmd.com and then `cd \\server\path\to\dir` and notice the error message `CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories.`)

That leaves you with mapping the path to a temporary drive letter using `net use` or instead of using `cd` use [`pushd`](https://superuser.com/questions/282963/browse-an-unc-path-using-windows-cmd-without-mapping-it-to-a-network-drive/399885#399885) instead, which basically maps your path to a temporary drive letter so you'll be able to access that file afterwards easily.

Using `pushd` will temporarily create a drive mapping to the network share and then change into a path relative to it. `popd` then will disconnects the share and return to your previous current directory.